# How to convert (x, y, k) to k-matrix with x as rows, y as cols in Pandas / Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

As per title, I have a Pandas dataframe containing coordinates and a value (z) like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
     columns=['x', 'y', 'k'],
     data=((x, y, x * y) for x in range(3) for y in range(3)))
```

resulting in:

```
   x  y  k
0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  2  0
3  1  0  0
4  1  1  1
5  1  2  2
6  2  0  0
7  2  1  2
8  2  2  4
```

I want to obtain:

```
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  0  1  2
2  0  2  4
```

(where `x` values are now the rows and `y` values are now the columns).

What would be the most Pythonic way of doing this with Pandas?

This would be similar to obtaining a dense representation of a matrix from a sparse one.
Note: the `x` and `y` values could be anything (not necessarily integers that happen to map nicely indexes).

p.s. I know I could do two manual loops, but that's what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: That's definitely a duplicate for that, I just did not know this was called `pivot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df.pivot(index='x', columns='y', values='k')
y  0  1  2
x         
0  0  0  0
1  0  1  2
2  0  2  4
```

And to match desired output you can use:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.pivot(index='x', columns='y', values='k').values)
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  0  1  2
2  0  2  4
```